# What is the intended effect of importing/including an XSD into another XSD file when generating an XML file from XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

When I generate an XML file from an XSD file that has included one or more XSD files, is the resultant XML file supposed to also include the generated XML from the XSD file(s)?

cake.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           targetNamespace="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="bakery.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="cakeType.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Cake">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="cakeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="cakeType" type="cakeType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ingredients" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="instructions" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

bakery.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           targetNamespace="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Bakery">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="guid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="creationDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="update" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                            <xs:element name="updateBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="updateDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        </xs:all>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

cakeType.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           targetNamespace="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="CakeType"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="cakeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="angel"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="pound"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="cheese"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="chiffon"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="genoise"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="sponge"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

I understand the generated XML files would look like this:

cake.xsd.xml:

```
<bak:Cake xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
  <bak:cakeName>string</bak:cakeName>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:cakeType>chiffon</bak:cakeType>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:ingredients>string</bak:ingredients>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:instructions>string</bak:instructions>
</bak:Cake>
```

bakery.xsd.xml:

```
<bak:Bakery xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
  <bak:guid>string</bak:guid>
  <bak:creationDate>2008-09-28T19:49:45</bak:creationDate>
  <bak:update>
    <bak:updateBy>string</bak:updateBy>
    <bak:updateDate>2014-09-18T17:18:33</bak:updateDate>
  </bak:update>
  <bak:name>string</bak:name>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:description>string</bak:description>
</bak:Bakery>
```

cakeType.xsd.xml:

```
<bak:CakeType xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">anyType</bak:CakeType>
```

**Question: Why wouldn't it generate the XML file this way?**

(It is including the generated XML of the included XSD files)

cake.xsd.xml: (Does not validate)

```
<bak:Cake xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
  <bak:Bakery xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
    <bak:guid>string</bak:guid>
    <bak:creationDate>2008-09-28T19:49:45</bak:creationDate>
    <bak:update>
      <bak:updateBy>string</bak:updateBy>
      <bak:updateDate>2014-09-18T17:18:33</bak:updateDate>
    </bak:update>
    <bak:name>string</bak:name>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <bak:description>string</bak:description>
  </bak:Bakery>
  <bak:CakeType xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">anyType</bak:CakeType>
  <bak:cakeName>string</bak:cakeName>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:cakeType>chiffon</bak:cakeType>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:ingredients>string</bak:ingredients>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:instructions>string</bak:instructions>
</bak:Cake>
```

**EDIT:**
I found the answer I was looking for. In order to include the content of the bakery in the cake XML generation, I changed bakery to a type and added a new bakery element to cake. Now, any time I change the bakery content, it will be still included in the cake XML generation.

Changed bakery.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           targetNamespace="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Bakery"/>
    <xs:complexType name="bakeryType">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="guid" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="creationDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="update" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="updateBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                        <xs:element name="updateDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Changed cake.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           targetNamespace="https://www.examle.com/bakery"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="bakery.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="cakeType.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Cake">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="bakery" type="bakeryType"/>
                <xs:element name="cakeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="cakeType" type="cakeType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="ingredients" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="instructions" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now the generated XML file from the cake.xsd file validates and has the bakery elements included:

```
<bak:Cake xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
  <bak:bakery>
    <bak:guid>string</bak:guid>
    <bak:creationDate>2008-09-28T19:49:45</bak:creationDate>
    <bak:update>
      <bak:updateBy>string</bak:updateBy>
      <bak:updateDate>2014-09-18T17:18:33</bak:updateDate>
    </bak:update>
    <bak:name>string</bak:name>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <bak:description>string</bak:description>
  </bak:bakery>
  <bak:cakeName>string</bak:cakeName>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:cakeType>cheese</bak:cakeType>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:ingredients>string</bak:ingredients>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:instructions>string</bak:instructions>
</bak:Cake>
```

Comment: Generating XML instances from an XSD schema is something for which there are a number of tools, but it's not governed by any standard, and it's inevitably a somewhat unpredictable process because there are many different instance documents that conform to any given schema. You need to ask the question in terms of the specific software tool you are using.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I was generating XML from XSD using IntelliJ's menu option: `Tools > XML Actions > Generate XML Document from XSD Schema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The include element is used to add multiple schemas with the same target namespace to a document.

`cake.xsd` **needs** `cakeType.xsd` to generate an instance while it may also generate a `Bakery` type but does not strictly requires it.

XML instance generated from an xsd will have defined elements and no more than that but could have less. For `cake.xsd`, 3 of them are of `xs:string` type and 1 of `cakeType` type defined in `cakeType.xsd` but valid because of the `<xs:include schemaLocation="cakeType.xsd"/>` include:

```
<xs:element name="Cake">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="cakeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="cakeType" type="cakeType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ingredients" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="instructions" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Generating from `cake.xsd` returns the same as posted by the OP
`XMLBEANS_LIB='/usr/share/java/xmlbeans/' xsd2inst cake.xsd -name Cake`

`bakery.xsd` elements are not present on `cake.xsd` structure and thus will not appear on it, however, `Bakery` instance can be generated from `cake.xsd` due to the `include`

```
XMLBEANS_LIB='/usr/share/java/xmlbeans/' xsd2inst cake.xsd -name Bakery
```

Result

```
<bak:Bakery xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
  <bak:guid>string</bak:guid>
  <bak:creationDate>2008-09-28T22:49:45</bak:creationDate>
  <bak:update>
    <bak:updateBy>string</bak:updateBy>
    <bak:updateDate>2014-09-18T20:18:33</bak:updateDate>
  </bak:update>
  <bak:name>string</bak:name>
  <!--Optional:-->
  <bak:description>string</bak:description>
</bak:Bakery>
```

Minimal `Cake` instance could be

```
<bak:Cake xmlns:bak="https://www.examle.com/bakery">
  <bak:cakeName>string</bak:cakeName>
</bak:Cake>
```

Generating code with `xjc`will generate classes for `include` xsd as well

```
/home/lmc/projects/bin/jaxb-ri/bin/xjc.sh -p cake cake.xsd
Java major version: 11
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
cake/Bakery.java
cake/Cake.java
cake/CakeType.java
cake/ObjectFactory.java
cake/package-info.java
```

Comment: "bakery.xsd elements are not present on cake.xsd structure and thus will not appear on it, however, Bakery instance can be generated from cake.xsd due to the include":
If bakery.xsd elements are not present on cake.xsd, why then include it at all? Is it only so a `cake` can generate a `bakery` instance?

Comment: @DrewShirts that's a possibility but hard to say for sure. Might be related to the whole project those are in.

Comment: @DrewShirts generating all code from cake.xsd could be another reason for the includes. See answer update.